# Медленное обновление LONGBLOB в MariaDb

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Windows 10. Переехал с MySQL 8.0 на MariaDb 10.7, заодно перенес базу с обычного SSD на M.2.

Выполняется таск по обновлению поля LONGBLOB у примерно миллиона записей. Если на MySQL задача отрабатывала 20-30 минут, то теперь стала выполняться почти полтора часа.

Причем другая задача, где идет обновление фиксированных полей ускорилась раза в два-три.

Тип таблицы INNODB, настройки стандартные, добавил только

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2G
innodb_log_file_size = 256M
```

В чем может быть проблема?